# SPI CLOCK error between ST7920 <-> ESP32 WROOM32

Tags: esp32, lcd, esp-idf

I'm using an ESP32 WROOM32 DEVKIT board, a 128x64 display with ST7920 chip. My development environment is ESP-IDF in VSCode.
I created a project from scratch, added only the U8G2 library directly from the official repository on GitHub following the official documentation. I also added Kolban's component, the u8g2_esp32_hal to interface with the main u8g2 library.

The first time I used this combination of libraries, still last year, it worked perfectly.... after approximately 6 months without running the development environment, I returned to work on the project, reinstalled VSCode, ESP-IDF, U8G2, and U8G2_esp32_hal, all from the official repositories in their current versions. However, now my CPU started to restart repeatedly when I try to start SPI communication between the ESP32 and the ST7920.
I even suspected the hardware, so I got a new DEVKIT board, a new display, and connected the display directly to the board, without any peripherals, just display-esp, and the board keeps resetting...

My boot log is as follows:

```markdown
0x40080400: _init at ??:?

load:0x40080404,len:3876
entry 0x4008064c
.I (32) boot: ESP-IDF v5.1-dirty 2nd stage bootloader
I (33) boot: compile time Jul 21 2023 15:13:26
I (33) boot: Multicore bootloader
I (37) boot: chip revision: v3.1
I (41) boot.esp32: SPI Speed      : 40MHz
I (46) boot.esp32: SPI Mode       : DIO
I (50) boot.esp32: SPI Flash Size : 2MB
I (55) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...
I (60) boot: Partition Table:
I (64) boot: ## Label            Usage          Type ST Offset   Length
I (71) boot:  0 nvs              WiFi data        01 02 00009000 00006000
I (79) boot:  1 phy_init         RF data          01 01 0000f000 00001000
I (86) boot:  2 factory          factory app      00 00 00010000 00100000
I (94) boot: End of partition table
I (98) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=00010020 vaddr=3f400020 size=0b9d0h ( 47568) map
I (124) esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0001b9f8 vaddr=3ffb0000 size=0226ch (  8812) load
I (127) esp_image: segment 2: paddr=0001dc6c vaddr=40080000 size=023ach (  9132) load
I (133) esp_image: segment 3: paddr=00020020 vaddr=400d0020 size=17db0h ( 97712) map
I (173) esp_image: segment 4: paddr=00037dd8 vaddr=400823ac size=0b2c8h ( 45768) load
I (199) boot: Loaded app from partition at offset 0x10000
I (199) boot: Disabling RNG early entropy source...
I (211) cpu_start: Multicore app
I (211) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.
I (211) cpu_start: Starting app cpu, entry point is 0x4008119c
0x4008119c: call_start_cpu1 at /home/wka/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/cpu_start.c:154

I (198) cpu_start: App cpu up.
I (229) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
I (229) cpu_start: cpu freq: 160000000 Hz
I (229) cpu_start: Application information:
I (234) cpu_start: Project name:     ST7920
I (239) cpu_start: App version:      1
I (243) cpu_start: Compile time:     Jul 21 2023 15:12:36
I (249) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:  71d26c1d383068f3...
I (255) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          v5.1-dirty
I (261) cpu_start: Min chip rev:     v0.0
I (265) cpu_start: Max chip rev:     v3.99 
I (270) cpu_start: Chip rev:         v3.1
I (275) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
I (282) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 00001920 (6 KiB): DRAM
I (288) heap_init: At 3FFB2F18 len 0002D0E8 (180 KiB): DRAM
I (294) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM
I (301) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM
I (307) heap_init: At 4008D674 len 0001298C (74 KiB): IRAM
I (315) spi_flash: detected chip: generic
I (318) spi_flash: flash io: dio
W (322) spi_flash: Detected size(4096k) larger than the size in the binary image header(2048k). Using the size in the binary image header.
I (336) app_start: Starting scheduler on CPU0
I (340) app_start: Starting scheduler on CPU1
I (340) main_task: Started on CPU0
I (350) main_task: Calling app_main()
I (350) gpio: GPIO[5]| InputEn: 0| OutputEn: 1| OpenDrain: 0| Pullup: 0| Pulldown: 1| Intr:0 
I (360) gpio: GPIO[22]| InputEn: 0| OutputEn: 1| OpenDrain: 0| Pullup: 0| Pulldown: 1| Intr:0 
E (370) esp_clk_tree: esp_clk_tree_src_get_freq_hz(21): unknown clk src
E (370) spi_master: spi_bus_add_device(368): invalid sclk speed
E (380) err: esp_err_t = 258

assert failed: u8g2_esp32_spi_byte_cb u8g2_esp32_hal.c:89 (0 && "spi_bus_add_device(HOST, &dev_config, &handle_spi)")


Backtrace: 0x400817be:0x3ffb4eb0 0x40086291:0x3ffb4ed0 0x4008c201:0x3ffb4ef0 0x400d5586:0x3ffb5010 0x400d5f10:0x3ffb5090 0x400d57fe:0x3ffb50b0 0x400d613d:0x3ffb50d0 0x400d621c:0x3ffb5100 0x400e62d9:0x3ffb5120 0x400d5421:0x3ffb5140 0x400e7620:0x3ffb5210 0x40088941:0x3ffb5240
0x400817be: panic_abort at /home/wka/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/panic.c:452

0x40086291: esp_system_abort at /home/wka/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/esp_system_chip.c:84

0x4008c201: __assert_func at /home/wka/esp/esp-idf/components/newlib/assert.c:81

0x400d5586: u8g2_esp32_spi_byte_cb at /home/wka/ST7920/components/u8g2-hal-esp-idf/src/u8g2_esp32_hal.c:89 (discriminator 5)

0x400d5f10: u8x8_cad_001 at /home/wka/ST7920/components/u8g2/csrc/u8x8_cad.c:355

0x400d57fe: u8x8_d_helper_display_init at /home/wka/ST7920/components/u8g2/csrc/u8x8_display.c:68

0x400d613d: u8x8_d_st7920_common at /home/wka/ST7920/components/u8g2/csrc/u8x8_d_st7920.c:94

0x400d621c: u8x8_d_st7920_128x64 at /home/wka/ST7920/components/u8g2/csrc/u8x8_d_st7920.c:326

0x400e62d9: u8x8_InitDisplay at /home/wka/ST7920/components/u8g2/csrc/u8x8_display.c:137

0x400d5421: app_main at /home/wka/ST7920/main/main.c:55

0x400e7620: main_task at /home/wka/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/app_startup.c:208 (discriminator 13)

0x40088941: vPortTaskWrapper at /home/wka/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/xtensa/port.c:162





ELF file SHA256: 71d26c1d383068f3

Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:7084
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:15576
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:4
.0x40080400: _init at ??:?
```

The reason for the reset is specifically the lines below:

```
E (370) esp_clk_tree: esp_clk_tree_src_get_freq_hz(21): unknown clk src
E (370) spi_master: spi_bus_add_device(368): invalid sclk speed
E (380) err: esp_err_t = 258

assert failed: u8g2_esp32_spi_byte_cb u8g2_esp32_hal.c:89 (0 && "spi_bus_add_device(HOST, &dev_config, &handle_spi)")
```

I realized that the error is related to the speed of my SPI, but I remember not having changed anything in relation to the SPI speed the last time I was able to make everything work. And this time it also doesn't work, even with a clean project, with all the default settings.

I tried adjusting the clock speed to 1MHz, 10MHz, and 530KHz when invoking the spi_bus_add_device( function within the u8g2_esp32_hal component, but any speed I put the cyclic reset continues.

Below my complete main code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <driver/gpio.h>
#include <driver/spi_master.h>
#include <esp_log.h>
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <u8g2.h>

#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "u8g2_esp32_hal.h"

// CLK - GPIO 18
#define PIN_CLK 18

// MOSI - GPIO 23
#define PIN_MOSI 23

// RESET - GPIO 22
#define PIN_RESET 22

// DC - GPIO -1
#define PIN_DC U8G2_ESP32_HAL_UNDEFINED

// CS - GPIO 05
#define PIN_CS 05
static char tag[] = "test_SST7920";
void app_main(void)
{
  u8g2_esp32_hal_t u8g2_esp32_hal = U8G2_ESP32_HAL_DEFAULT;
  u8g2_esp32_hal.bus.spi.clk = PIN_CLK;
  u8g2_esp32_hal.bus.spi.mosi = PIN_MOSI;
  u8g2_esp32_hal.bus.spi.cs = PIN_CS;
  u8g2_esp32_hal.dc = PIN_DC;
  u8g2_esp32_hal.reset = PIN_RESET;
  u8g2_esp32_hal_init(u8g2_esp32_hal);

  u8g2_t u8g2;  // a structure which will contain all the data for one display
    u8g2_Setup_st7920_128x64_f(
        &u8g2,
        U8G2_R0,
        u8g2_esp32_spi_byte_cb,
        u8g2_esp32_gpio_and_delay_cb);  // init u8g2 structure




    u8g2_esp32_hal_init(u8g2_esp32_hal);



    

  u8g2_InitDisplay(&u8g2);  // send init sequence to the display, display is in
                            // sleep mode after this,

  u8g2_SetPowerSave(&u8g2, 0);  // wake up display
  u8g2_ClearBuffer(&u8g2);
  u8g2_DrawBox(&u8g2, 10, 20, 20, 30);
  u8g2_SetFont(&u8g2, u8g2_font_ncenB14_tr);
  u8g2_DrawStr(&u8g2, 0, 15, "Hello World!");
  u8g2_SendBuffer(&u8g2);

  ESP_LOGD(tag, "All done!");
}
```

and below my code of the u8g2_esp32_spi_byte_cb() function of the u8g2_esp32_hal component, it is in this function that I tried those different speeds for the SPI clock:

```
uint8_t u8g2_esp32_spi_byte_cb(u8x8_t* u8x8,
                               uint8_t msg,
                               uint8_t arg_int,
                               void* arg_ptr) {
  ESP_LOGD(TAG, "spi_byte_cb: Received a msg: %d, arg_int: %d, arg_ptr: %p",
           msg, arg_int, arg_ptr);
  switch (msg) {
    case U8X8_MSG_BYTE_SET_DC:
      if (u8g2_esp32_hal.dc != U8G2_ESP32_HAL_UNDEFINED) {
        gpio_set_level(u8g2_esp32_hal.dc, arg_int);
      }
      break;

    case U8X8_MSG_BYTE_INIT: {
      if (u8g2_esp32_hal.bus.spi.clk == U8G2_ESP32_HAL_UNDEFINED ||
          u8g2_esp32_hal.bus.spi.mosi == U8G2_ESP32_HAL_UNDEFINED ||
          u8g2_esp32_hal.bus.spi.cs == U8G2_ESP32_HAL_UNDEFINED) {
        break;
      }

      spi_bus_config_t bus_config;
      memset(&bus_config, 0, sizeof(spi_bus_config_t));
      bus_config.sclk_io_num = u8g2_esp32_hal.bus.spi.clk;   // CLK
      bus_config.mosi_io_num = u8g2_esp32_hal.bus.spi.mosi;  // MOSI
      bus_config.miso_io_num = GPIO_NUM_NC;                  // MISO
      bus_config.quadwp_io_num = GPIO_NUM_NC;                // Not used
      bus_config.quadhd_io_num = GPIO_NUM_NC;                // Not used
      // ESP_LOGI(TAG, "... Initializing bus.");
      ESP_ERROR_CHECK(spi_bus_initialize(HOST, &bus_config, 1));

      spi_device_interface_config_t dev_config;
      dev_config.address_bits = 0;
      dev_config.command_bits = 0;
      dev_config.dummy_bits = 0;
      dev_config.mode = 0;
      dev_config.duty_cycle_pos = 0;
      dev_config.cs_ena_posttrans = 0;
      dev_config.cs_ena_pretrans = 0;
      dev_config.clock_speed_hz = 530000;
      dev_config.spics_io_num = u8g2_esp32_hal.bus.spi.cs;
      dev_config.flags = 0;
      dev_config.queue_size = 200;
      dev_config.pre_cb = NULL;
      dev_config.post_cb = NULL;
      // ESP_LOGI(TAG, "... Adding device bus.");
      ESP_ERROR_CHECK(spi_bus_add_device(HOST, &dev_config, &handle_spi));

      break;
    }

    case U8X8_MSG_BYTE_SEND: {
      spi_transaction_t trans_desc;
      trans_desc.addr = 0;
      trans_desc.cmd = 0;
      trans_desc.flags = 0;
      trans_desc.length = 8 * arg_int;  // Number of bits NOT number of bytes.
      trans_desc.rxlength = 0;
      trans_desc.tx_buffer = arg_ptr;
      trans_desc.rx_buffer = NULL;

      // ESP_LOGI(TAG, "... Transmitting %d bytes.", arg_int);
      ESP_ERROR_CHECK(spi_device_transmit(handle_spi, &trans_desc));
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}  // u8g2_esp32_spi_byte_cb
```

Why can't I even run the example codes anymore, whereas last year everything worked perfectly, I even developed several applications with screens, menus, and animations on this same hardware...

---

I kept looking for the issue and found the root cause, but I'm not exactly sure why the problem started happening. I believe it could be due to an update in ESP-IDF or FreeRTOS, someone with more experience in embedded systems might know...

Basically, in the u8g2_esp32_spi_byte_cb() function when filling out the fields of the dev_config variable to send to the spi_bus_add_device() function, none of the documentation I found instructed to pass the dev_config.clock_source field, but from what I saw in the functions that are called from here, this information is needed.

So, the error above was caused because the dev_config.clock_source field is not being filled in the u8g2_esp32_spi_byte_cb function before passing the dev_config as a parameter in the line ESP_ERROR_CHECK(spi_bus_add_device(HSPI_HOST, &dev_config, &handle_spi));

This way the initialization for the dev_config parameter would look like this:

```
          spi_device_interface_config_t dev_config;
          dev_config.address_bits     = 0;
          dev_config.command_bits     = 0;
          dev_config.dummy_bits       = 0;
          dev_config.mode             = 0;
          dev_config.duty_cycle_pos   = 0;
          dev_config.cs_ena_posttrans = 0;
          dev_config.cs_ena_pretrans  = 0;
          dev_config.clock_speed_hz   = 10000;
      dev_config.clock_source     = SPI_CLK_SRC_DEFAULT; //SOC_MOD_CLK_APB;
          dev_config.spics_io_num     = u8g2_esp32_hal.cs;
          dev_config.flags            = 0;
          dev_config.queue_size       = 200;
          dev_config.pre_cb           = NULL;
          dev_config.post_cb          = NULL;
          //ESP_LOGI(TAG, "... Adding device bus.");
          ESP_ERROR_CHECK(spi_bus_add_device(HSPI_HOST, &dev_config, &handle_spi));
```

That's it. Looking at the current ESP-IDF code, I can't understand how my previous code worked without this field, as browsing through previous versions of ESP-IDF on GitHub, this information was always mandatory.

I won't mark this thread as resolved since, as I mentioned, I don't understand why it worked before. Therefore, my solution might not be the correct one, or everything I said may not make sense, but as I'm behind schedule with my project, I won't delve further into this investigation.

Cheers!

Comment: I've run into a similar issue the reason was that some of the ESP-IDF structs weren't properly initialized with 0. They keep adding new fields to the structs. So a robust, version independen initialization is needed. The likely suspect is the struct passed to `spi_bus_add_device()`. Try adding `memset(& dev_config, 0, sizeof(dev_config));`

Comment: Perfect Codo, indeed the problem was with the initialization of the dev_config variable. Starting from some version, which I didn't look up, providing a valid value for the clock_source field became mandatory... I started going into the references of the function calls and eventually found the solution.

THANKS

Comment: Does your previous working code called the `u8g2_esp32_hal_init(u8g2_esp32_hal);` twice like the code you shown?